# itunesconnect unable to process request

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I want to change my app's name in the app store. To do that, I need to first delete my old app from the app store.

I went over to itunesconnect and clicked Rights and Pricing on my app.
and received this

[image]

I tried it on 3 different computers, and for the sake of the test tried also with a different Apple account that I have, the same result.

I then deleted all browsing data and cookies and tried again. Still the same. Then I tried rebooting my computer. Still the same.

I need to delete the app from the app store. What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not alone I can confirm that I get the same screen:

[image]

I would say there is a problem with the site itself.

<del>Sorry but try again later, or send them an email as suggested...</del>

Now to answer your question, you don't really have to delete the app, you can change edit the details, but I believe you will need to submit an update for that.

Comment: I tried clicking on edit meta data, but the app name is not editable

Comment: @LenaBru because you need to create a new update. once submitted apple does not let you change screenshot, keywords or rename the app.

Comment: i just need to add new version ?

Comment: Yes add a new version and you can change anything, the only time you will have to delete the app is if you want to change the bundle identifier

Comment: can i upload the "same" version of the app, without changing the version code ?

Comment: no you cannot do that, because updating means a new version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59681/discussion-between-meda-and-lena-bru).